# progressbar atinge o valor máximo mas visualmente não se preenche c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Estou trabalhando com um software em C#, no qual depois de uma tela do login, aparece um `splashscreen` com uma `progressbar` que quando chega ao seu valor máximo `(100)`, ela chama o formulário principal do programa.

O problema é que a `progressbar` atinge o valor de `100`, mas visualmente na `splashscreen`, ela não é preenchida completamente (o que deveria pois chegou ao seu valor máximo estipulado) e então acaba chamando o próximo formulário em estar completamente carregada. Vou deixar abaixo o código  da `splash`, obrigado!

Obs.: Os locais comentados são de uma outra coisa que estava testando portanto não são relevantes no caso.

```
private void EfectTime()
{
    //SplashTimer.Interval = 100;
    SplashTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(SplashTimer_Tick);
    SplashTimer.Enabled = true;
    //this.Opacity = 1;
}

//  private bool Efect = true;

private void SplashTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    pgrBar.Increment(1);

    //if (Efect) 
    //{
    //    this.Opacity -= 0.01D;
    //}

    if (pgrBar.Value == 100)
    {
        //Efect = false;

        SplashTimer.Enabled = false;
        FrmTelaPrincipal frmTelaprincipal = new FrmTelaPrincipal();
        frmTelaprincipal.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: Até que ponto ela chega? Isso não deve ao fato de que a tela principal abre logo que o progresso chega em 100?

Comment: sim realmente, ela não se completa pois o próximo formulário é aberto. Mas o carregamento dela não é sincronizado com seu valor? penso que seria suposto que ao chegasse a 100 ela estaria totalmente preenchida e imediatamente chamar o formulário.

Comment: Possivelmente ela está, só não dá tempo de ver ***=)***

Answer (score 2):

Mova a linha do incremento para depois da condição.

```
private void SplashTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    //if (Efect) 
    //{
    //    this.Opacity -= 0.01D;
    //}

    if (pgrBar.Value == 100)
    {
        //Efect = false;

        SplashTimer.Enabled = false;
        FrmTelaPrincipal frmTelaprincipal = new FrmTelaPrincipal();
        frmTelaprincipal.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    pgrBar.Increment(1);
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, e ainda abriu o formulário duas vezes.

Comment: Eu criei um programa de teste e acabei de verificar novamente e só isso bastou. Ao mover a linha do incremento, ela não pode ficar dentro da condição, e sim, abaixo. Confere o valor da propriedade Maximum (para 100) e o Step (para 1) do progressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas resolvi assim:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int prog = 0;        

private void tempo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (prog != 105)
            //if(pbIni.Value <= pbIni.Maximum)
            {
                pbIni.Increment(1);
                prog++;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);//Esta linha apenas se quiser mais esperar um tempinho a mais
                Application.Exit();
            }

        }
```